# How to debug Undeclared Entity errors in Microsoft XLSX files

Tags: xml, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm generating large Excel files, in xlsx format. The files contain 100+ thousand rows, with 100+ columns.

When I open one of the files, I get this: "Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part with XML error.  Undeclared entity. Line 23350, column 3794."

I'll be going through the input data to try to find the problem, but I'm wondering if there's a better, faster, easier way to figure out what Excel doesn't like about this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel says it's an XML error, so any XML parser should report the same error. The easiest way to locate the error is probably to load the same XML file into an XML IDE such as oxygen or Stylus Studio.